# Can't send customer note email notification in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have the following code to try to send an order notification email to the customer in WooCommerce.

I have some other code that already made the custom order status "reminder". I can also select this new "reminder" from the Bulk actions dropdown box in the orders page in WooCommerce.

If a select an order and select custom order status "reminder" from the dropdown box it successfully adds a note on the order on that order's page, but it does not send a notification email to the user.

How come?

```
// Do the bulk action from the selected orders
add_filter('handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'status_bulk_action_edit_shop_order', 10, 3);
function status_bulk_action_edit_shop_order($redirect_to, $action, $post_ids) {
    if ($action === 'reminder') {

        foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {
            $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
            $the_order_id = $order->get_id();
            $note = 'Test1';
            $order->update_status('reminder');
            send_order_note_email($the_order_id, $note);
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}

function send_order_note_email($order_id, $note)
{
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Check if order exists and is a valid order
    if (!$order) {
        return;
    }

    // Add the note to the order
    $order->add_order_note($note);

    // Send the email notification
    $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Note_Customer'];
    if ($mailer) {
        $mailer->trigger($order_id, $note);
    }
}
```

Tried various functions and different hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making things much more complicated: 
[The `WC_Order` method `add_order_note()` has an additional argument `$is_customer_note`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.6/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php#L1931-L1939) that need to bet set to `1` or `true`, and send automatically the `customer_note` email notification by itself.

You can use 2 approaches:

1. Add a note to customer when order status get changed to "reminder" *(the cleanest way and complete way)*:

```php
// Do the bulk action from the selected orders
add_filter('handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'status_bulk_action_edit_shop_order', 10, 3);
function status_bulk_action_edit_shop_order($redirect_to, $action, $post_ids) {
    if ($action === 'reminder') {

        foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {
            $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
            $order->update_status('reminder');
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}

// Add a note to customer when order get "reminder" status (sends the email notification)
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_reminder', 'add_reminder_order_note_to_customer', 10, 2);
function add_reminder_order_note_to_customer( $order_id, $order )
{
    // Define the customer note to be sent
    $note_to_customer = 'Test1';

    // Add the customer note to the order
    $order->add_order_note($note_to_customer, 1);
}
```

2. Add a note to customer when changing order status to "reminder" via bulk actions:

```php
// Do the bulk action from the selected orders
add_filter('handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'status_bulk_action_edit_shop_order', 10, 3);
function status_bulk_action_edit_shop_order($redirect_to, $action, $post_ids) {
    if ($action === 'reminder') {

        foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {
            $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
            $order->update_status('reminder');

            // Define the customer note to be sent
            $note_to_customer = 'Test1';

            // Add the customer note to the order
            $order->add_order_note($note_to_customer, 1);
        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Both ways should work.

Comment: Hello LoicTheAztec, thank you for your reply. I used the first approach and it works very nice. I see I made things overly complicated before yes :-) Great, thanks again.